# will self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem support Array?

Tags: iphone

i want to include segmented control in navigation item with flexible space.bcos it has 2 control .. i want to bring in the center....i tried follow .. will u help ? ...the line...

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [NSArray   arrayWithObjects:segmentBarItem,flexibleSpaceButtonItem,nil];
```

gives error?

```
 UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
 initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

[segmentedControl release];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
target:nil action:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentBarItem,flexibleSpaceButtonItem,nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the objective of ur problem is to add more than one button to the right bar button item?

If it is you can do it in this way......

```
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45)];
        [tools setTintColor:[self.navigationController.navigationBar tintColor]];
        NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

        UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
        [segmentedControl release];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil 
        action:nil];

        [buttons addObject:flexibleSpaceButtonItem];
        [flexibleSpaceButtonItem release];

        [buttons addObject:segmentBarItem];
        [segmentBarItem release];



        [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

        [buttons release];

        UIBarButtonItem *myBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBtn;

        [myBtn release];
        [tools release];
```

Don't forget to vote if this solves ur problem .... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work; `rightBarButtonItem` is of type `UIBarButtonItem *`, and you're trying to stuff an `NSArray *` into it.  As far as I know, there's no standard way to put an extra button into the navigation bar.